# How can I select customers who have certain number of orders and other conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am studying SQL. There is one particular query which I find difficult to implement (using PostgreSQL database).

Could someone help me with that?

**Query** : "Who are the customers who have at least one order which includes products from at least 3 product categories?".

The result should include 2 columns: `customerID` and `Quantity of orders`.

The tables are the following:

1. **Product**  `ProductID (id of a product)`|`ProductCategoryID (product categories)` both integers.
2. **SalesOrderDetail** :`SalesOrderID (id order)`|`SalesOrderDetailID`|`OrderQty`|`ProductID`, all of them integers .
3. **SalesOrderHeader**: `SalesOrderID`|`CustomerID`, both integers.

The only thing I got  so far is the first part of the statement:

```
select salesorderheader.customerID, salesorderdetail.orderqty 
from salesorderheader, salesorderdetail;
```

Sample data:

```
 productid | productcategoryid  
-----------+-------------------  
         1 |                 2                  
         2 |                 2                 
         3 |                 3                  
         4 |          

salesorderid  | salesorderdetailid | orderqty | productid   
--------------+--------------------+----------+-----------  
        43659 |                  1 |        1 |       776  
        43659 |                  2 |        3 |       777  
        43659 |                  3 |        1 |       778


salesorderid | customerid   

--------------+------------  
        43659 |      29825  
        43660 |      29672  
        43661 |      29734
```

Comment: SO is not a site where homework questions are answered. There is also not enough information to answer the question. Finally you should show what you have tried so far (your code up until this point).

Comment: Igor which informations are still needed?I ll post my tries soon but they failed so far.By the way i **wont** have any personal gain from this query since i wont be examined in that.I just ask for the sake of knowledge. Thanks for your reply

Comment: When asking sql questions you should post the DDL (data definition language), this includes the table(s) structure and relationships. Also post sample data and the expected results from the query. Finally it is expected that your code does not work, otherwise you would not be posting the question on SO. Post that not working code with any additional explanations that clarify what you have tried to this point.

Comment: @Igor: To be clear, asking homework questions can have a place in SO if done properly (though many don't like it regardless). See here: [Stack Overflow and homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253792/stack-overflow-and-homework-questions). Though technically OP did post what he has done so far, I'm not sure it shows a lot of effort on his part.

Comment: @sstan - good to know, I thought it was generally frowned upon. I will retract my close vote.

Comment: Hard to solve something like this out of the head :) Here you can create a sandbox for us http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15

Comment: Your **SalesOrderDetail.productid** values do not match any existing product. Did you swap columns? Also, **SalesOrderHeader.salesorderid** values exist without child records in **SalesOrderDetail**.

Comment: trincot i just used `limit` to show of a sample of my database. unfortunately Its pretty large to print the whole database

Comment: **Philip** i am working on that, i ll post a sheme soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two approaches here:

1) Generate a subquery which contains the count a salesOrderID and the count of Distinct ProductCategories used for that salesorder.

```
SELECT customerID, count(Distinct OH.SalesOrderID) SalesOrdersWithMoreThan3Categories
FROM SalesOrderHeader OH
INNER JOIN (SELECT OD.SalesOrderID, Count(Distinct P.ProductCategoryID) Cnt
            FROM SalesOrderDetail OD 
            INNER JOIN Product P
              on P.ProudctID = OD.ProductID
            GROUP BY OD.SalesOrderID) B
   on OH.SalesOrderID = B.SaleOrderID
  and B.cnt >=3
GROUP BY  OH.customerID
```

2) Use Exists to identify orderDetails a count of distinct productCategories >=3

```
SELECT OH.customerID, count(Distinct OH.SalesOrderID) SalesOrdersWithMoreThan3Categories
FROM SalesOrderHeader OH
WHERE exists (SELECT 1
            FROM SalesOrderDetail OD 
            INNER JOIN Product P
              on P.ProudctID = OD.ProductID
            WHERE OH.SalesOrderID = OD.SalesOrderID
            GROUP BY OD.SalesOrderID
            HAVING Count(Distinct P.ProductCategoryID) >=3)
GROUP BY  OH.customerID
```

Comment: Thank you fro your answer. Your first approach results in: `column reference "salesorderid" is ambiguous` .  i ll try the second one soon

Comment: Updated.  Should have had an OH on SalesOrderID on the distinct of first Select.

Comment: Now the error message is: `column "oh.customerid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` and the second approach wont produce any result.

Comment: now the 1st approach produces result. Thanks  **xQbert**